# Something wrong with comment time-stamps

Tags: support, design, comments

With the new site design I am experiencing a problem with comment time-stamps.  As the page is loading they appear normally, following the user name, but after the page has loaded they disappear.  The page shows that the date is still there, e.g.

```
<span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment152523_51652"><span title="2014-06-27 21:09:14Z" class="relativetime-clean">Jun 27 '14 at 21:09</span></a></span>
```

However the element apparently is suppressed by style sheets.  Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Can you give us some information about your browser/OS? Also check if you have any scripts running that may be causing this? I'm not able to Reproduce in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: I cannot confirm this behavior. Tested with Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Catija I am using the http://www.palemoon.org/ browser, latest version, under Windows 7 x64.  I have userscripts and ad blockers disabled.  I realize Pale Moon is uncommon but it was working before, and I hope this isn't the start of further incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem resolved after updating to Pale Moon v28.3.0 which includes, among other changes:

> Fixed an issue with lazy frame construction on `display:contents` elements. This should solve e.g. the use of mathjax in comments on stackoverflow.

I'm not sure if that's the specific fix, but it at least indicates that the developer was aware of issues with Stack Overflow.